# How to determine which xcode was used to develop from code

Tags: ios, xcode

I have iOS app source code i want to determine which version of xcode was used to develop the project.

In `project.pbxproj` when i go to section `/* Begin PBXProject section */` it says

```
compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 3.2";
```

so my guess is it has been developed on some 4.x version not on xcode 5. Please suggest.

Comment: Nsstring *str = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does knowing the Xcode version of the project.pbxproj get you?

Comment: @user1118321 after apple,s announcement about feb 1 it has been a task to verify that vendor will not mess up at last moment.i want to know the version of xcode used to make the project.

Comment: @amar in that case, open the project in xcode 5, convert it, use iOS7 sdk as base sdk-kit and remove all the errors

Comment: I think this is good question. For example when automating build of multiple apps it is necessary to know what xcode version need to be used to build specific app. Naturally it is possible to add a file containing xcode version and reading it from there, but using something that is automatically generated by xcode would be more useful. As far as I can see compatibilityVersion can not be used for that.

Comment: @staticVoidMan thats exactly what i wanted to avoid at the last moment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have .xcarchive or .ipa file that is associated with the project then you can determine the version of Xcode that was used to build it.  Xcode adds, among other things, a "DTXcode" key to the info.plist upon build.

So open your .xcarchive file with Finder or rename the .ipa file to .zip and open that with Finder.
Navigate to find the app bundle file - that's the one with the .app extension.  Right click and "Show Package Contents."  Find the info.plist and open that with a text editor.

You will see something like:

```
<key>DTXcode</key>
<string>0611</string>
```

In this case, 611 is Xcode 6.1.1.

Alternatively, if you have access to iTunesConnect, you can see the details of a binary that was uploaded.  Look for "Build Details" and find a key called "Build SDK."  It will be an alphanumeric string, e.g. 12B411.

Since Apple usually only bundles one version of the SDK with Xcode, you can use this site to find the version of Xcode that corresponds to the SDK: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

In the case of 12B411, I see that is was iOS 8.1 final, which was bundled with Xcode 6.1 build 6A1052d.

Answer (score 16):

If you open the project.pbxproj file and search for `CreatedOnToolsVersion`, it looks like that will give you what you want here, at least with newer versions of Xcode.

I see it set to 7.3.1 in one of my projects and 8.3.2 in another, created with that version of Xcode.

Comment: THIS is the real answer. This doesn't involve anything other than your .xcodeproj file

Comment: I cannot give both of them correct answer.This answer is right for all cases when you have code. +1. But one point  CreatedOnToolsVersion shows the xcode which was used to create not the last one used.Mine shows 7.*** where as current is 9.0 which i use

Comment: good one ! thanks , I have CreatedOnToolsVersion = 11.6;

Comment: Bookmarked for being the real answer! For you shell users out there, `grep 'CreatedOnToolsVersion' project.pbxproj` can be a real handy one to glean from this~

Answer (score 7):

On Xcode 11-12, This works for me:
in your schema file it mentioned the last used Xcode version.

```
YourProject.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/YourSchema.xcscheme
```

`LastUpgradeVersion = "1160"` means Xcode 11.6

Xcode changes this value when you click on `Update to recommended settings` warning!.
Even if you uncheck all recommended settings and click `done` it still changes the number.

Comment: I believe this ignores the patch version, i.e. for 13.2.1 I see `LastUpgradeVersion = "1320"`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the answer here referring to `LastUpgradeVersion` doesn't seem entirely correct.

Perhaps it works fine enough for projects that still use their original version, but after upgrading our project to build with Xcode 14.3 *(was 10.3)*, the `LastUpgradeVersion` entry in `*.xcscheme` remained the same ("1030").

**However,** the `LastUpgradeCheck` entry in `*/project.pbxproj` updated accordingly.

If ye got Git, then

```bash
git grep -F LastUpgradeCheck -- '*/project.pbxproj'
```

*(for you speed runners out there)*

Comment: 'doh!  Silly me. `LastUpgradeCheck` is right next to `CreatedOnToolsVersion` in the same file, and the latter is more human-readable and accurate to the minor version.